# Dynamically created element used for Raphael canvas

Tags: backbone.js, raphael, requirejs, graphael

I have created a Backbone.js/Require.js application that dynamically loads HTML templates to use as "pages" in the application. This means my main HTML page looks like so.

```
<head>
  // Necessary CSS and Javascripts here
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

And then I used underscore templates to render new elements dynamically to the DOM. However, a new feature requires the use of a Raphael.js chart. I created a new element `<div id='canvas'></div>` and call `Raphael('canvas')` but since the canvas element wasn't there on DOM ready, Raphael can't see the newly created element.

I have attempted to use a jQuery selector in place of the id reference like so `Raphael($('#canvas'))` but this attaches the canvas to the body element and not my container element.

Any suggestions on how to bind a Raphael canvas to a dynamically created element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to overcome this issue is by creating an empty element in the view and binding everything onto that. I have never worked with Raphael, but I think this could work:

```
var someView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: document.createElement('div'), // This creates a DOM element '<div></div>'

    initialize: function(){
        Raphael(this.el); // Attach Raphael, you could also go with jQuery
    },

    render: function(){
        jQuery('#container').append(this.el); // Add to DOM somehow
    }
})
```

Comment: I woke up this morning going, "duh!" And realized your answer was indeed correct. I forgot one of the main principles of Backbone views is that you can build them in memory, and then append them to the DOM. Thanks for the brain jolt!

Comment: My edit was the correct way... I wanted to give you the reps though... please accept my edit so others can see EXACTLY how to do this or I will just answer the question myself

Comment: @jibsales The edit was rejected by other based on it changing most of the meaning of my answer. I believe my answer is more generally applicable, your answer is more specific for your situation. Thanks for wanting to give me credit though, it is much appreciated. You are of course free to do as you please and answer it yourself :). Glad I could help getting the ol' brain up and running again, we have all been there and we all keep going there.

Answer (score 4):

```
Raphael($('#canvas').first(), '100%', '100%')
```

Though I had errors else where, the main issue that caused Raphael not to fire was forgetting that a jQuery selector passes an array of Elements and Raphael's constructor want's a single element. Raphael was attaching itself to the body because it was the top level parent of the selector's result.

Mosselman was also correct in pointing out that you can build a view in Backbone entirely in memory and then append it to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

seems like a good approach is to either throw an event after the template has been added to the DOM and have your call to Raphael('canvas') listen for that event or use a callback to trigger Raphael('canvas'). in both cases you are ensuring that you don't call Raphael('canvas') before the target element is in place.

very roughly, something like this:

```
//from your raphael module / code
$(document).on('canvasAdded', function(){
    var paper = Raphael('canvas');
    //stuff!
});

//after you are sure your template has rendered
$(document).trigger('canvasAdded');
```

you probably want to make some kind of .init() method and call that from the event handler (vs. what I show above) but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: No dice. I can see the element when I call console.log(document) immediately after the template is added to the DOM and I can traverse the resulting tree in Firebug to find the added 'canvas' element, but when I call document.getElementById('canvas') I get null.

Comment: can you init raphael via firebug's or chrome's js console? (just load yr app and get it into the state you expect then enter Raphael('canvas'); )

Comment: nope... that returns an undefined for the element... I'm beginning to think this isn't possible, as I've now sandboxed several event delegation methods without the use of Backbone/Require and I'm getting the same results.

Comment: hmmm... that's usually a sign that either a) your selector is wrong or b) the element isn't actually in the DOM. does $('#canvas').length return > 0? are you creating the element within an iframe? in chrome's dev tools, you can select the element in the "elements" tab.. then in the console tab do $0 <enter> and it will return a ref to the selected element... you could then do Raphael($0) and see what happens (should get a proper obj back). anyway, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is too old question, but anyway it can help to someone. Its important to be sure that your view is placed on page, so use something like onShow functionality, or render. But anyway Raphael will not show right because if your send to Raphael this.$el or anything similar it will not accept it like you expect. What You need to do is something like this.$el.first() or this.$el[0].